# TmxMapLoader without libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing my own game without any frameworks and engines (except JBox2D cause I have very big troubles w/ physics). I need to load `.tmx` file into my game. The only ready-to-use option was LibGDX with his `TmxMapLoader`. I added dependency to project, ran and got quite expected crash:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle com.badlogic.gdx.Files.internal(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.resolvers.InternalFileHandleResolver.resolve(InternalFileHandleResolver.java:26)
```

What I supposed to do to load `.tmx` from assets using `TmxMapLoader`?
Probably the best solution would be porting game to LibGDX but I have no time and desire to study documentation and rework that I already have.

Comment: Don't use libgdx framework only for a tmxmaploader, the file format is very easy, just open on your notepad and analyse it, it's just a xml.. for more reference see [this link](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/)

Comment: The error says that it was not able to locate the tmx file file because the string you passed was a null :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use LibGDX framework and its file module, I'd suggest simply going through TMX-related code and convert it the way you want it. LibGDX is [open-sourced](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.java), after all. `FileHandle` is just a wrapper over `File` on most platforms, it should be straightforward to replace (or include in your project and used with `File` constructor). Java provides its own XML readers, so if it comes to that, you'll be able to replace any XML-related LibGDX code as well.

I'm afraid the default loader implementation loads textures as well, so without running an actual LibGDX application, it will not work. However, if you **don't** mind including LibGDX jars, you could try extending this class and removing all texture-related code or replacing it with your custom image-loading code.